# MVC3 Ajax.ActionLink Cache

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I've designed a regular model dialog, the modal dialog contains :

-Find link

-Partial View (to show the returned results).

To illustrate my problem, you'll find in the RouteValues I'm posting the current time in seconds. Everytime I click, I get the same result.

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("Find", "PopulateResults", "Contract", new { kind = DateTime.Now.Second },
                                      new AjaxOptions
                                      {
                                          UpdateTargetId = "results",
                                          HttpMethod = "POST",
                                          InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                                          LoadingElementId = "progress"

                                      }, new
                                      {
                                          @class = "button",
                                          id = "FindButton"
                                      }
                                    )
```

The controller gets the *kind* value and pass it to the partial view

```
 [HttpPost]
    [OutputCache(NoStore = true, VaryByParam = "", Duration = 0)]
    public ActionResult PopulateResults(int kind)
    {


        return PartialView("PopulateResults", kind);

    }
```

As I said, the value is always cached and it's not updated.

**Update**: Originally, I don't really want to post the current time and show it in the Partial View. 
In my modal dialog I have a textbox which is used for filtering the returned results. Actually, what happens, is that the value of the textbox is always cached.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm posting the current time in seconds

You are not posting the *current* time. You are posting the time (actually not the time but only the second) that was when the server rendered this page. If you want to post the current time use the client time.

Comment: I tried to post a string to the controller but it didn't work

Comment: @Anwar, what string are you talking about? Actually I don't think that you have a caching problem. You have disabled cache using the OutputCache attribute on the controller action and you are using a POST request which normally are not cached by browsers. So your problem lies somewhere else. If you are saying that you are getting all the time the same `kind` parameter inside your controller action this doesn't mean that the action is cached. If it was it wouldn't even be invoked. It's because everytime you are passing the same value.

Comment: you're correct, I've made two mistakes
First, when I was posting the current time in seconds

Comment: The Ajax.ActionLink works perfectly.
The problem lies here
 $('#FindButton').attr('href', function () {
                
                return this.href.replace('__secondParty__', $('#txtSecondParty').val());
            })